# Application hangs when calling a method from .jar

Tags: android, jar, android-ndk, java-native-interface, nsight

My application calls `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);` from `google-play-services.jar` via JNI.

In my Eclipse project everything is OK (so both the JNI part and java code work fine), but when the same code is being called from NSight Tegra project the application just hangs.

In my NSight Tegra project:

- JAR libraries are set up in project properties
- They are dexed during the build: `[dex] Using Pre-Dexed google-play-services-1cb26df6ef48c628203cda343aaaf971.jar <- <my path here>\Tegra-Android\Debug\libs\google-play-services.jar`
- I can find `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` in `classes.dex` inside the .apk

I'll appreciate any suggestions!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer!!!

The issue was solved when changed **Debug Mode** to **Native Code**. Seems the application stopped somewhere on a hidden breakpoint in java part.

Comment: @user3748298 asks "I am having hard time in adding external jar dependencies in tegra project. Please elaborate how did you make it?"

Comment: @user3748298 did you get your answer? If not, you could ask your own question.